# Add background image to Jupiter 4 WordPress Theme header

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a site using a Jupiter 4 theme. Within the dashboard there are options to configure the header layout, but there is nothing there to add a background image to the header.

The stylesheet is located at themes/jupiter/stylesheet/css/styles.css. In it, I have tried putting a `background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/header-miami-beach-sign.png');` in different id definitions that start with #mk-header, but no image is displaying. The header background is just a solid white color.

I'm trying to turn **this:**

[image: plain header]

into **this:**

[image: header with a feature background image]

Comment: Code or a link to the site would be needed in order to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jupiter 4 theme, everything is in Jupiter backend "theme options":

You can disable the toolbar and to set header height between 140px to 200px (or more if needed).

For styling go to "styling tab (or menu):

- First, you can unset (or reset) white backgrounds (to transparent) in "header".
- Then add in "backgrounds" section (selecting header area) you can set there your background image.

No need to overlap or add styles

Dont forget that Jupiter theme is responsive regarding your background image…

The most accurate way to solve issues with premium themes is reading documentation, searching over Jupiter support threads or asking on this support threads.

---- (update) ----

To set different images sizes you need to use CSS (this is just an example):

```css
.mk-header-bg.mk-background-stretch {
    background: transparent url('/myImage-hd.jpg') no-repeat !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .mk-header-bg.mk-background-stretch {
        background: transparent url('/myImage-big.jpg') no-repeat !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .mk-header-bg.mk-background-stretch {
        background: transparent url('/myImage-medium.jpg') no-repeat !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 588px) {
    .mk-header-bg.mk-background-stretch {
        background: transparent url('/myImage-medium-small.jpg') no-repeat !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .mk-header-bg.mk-background-stretch {
        background: transparent url('/myImage-small.jpg') no-repeat !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .mk-header-bg.mk-background-stretch {
        background: transparent url('/myImage-very-small.jpg') no-repeat !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the image working for my screen size. Unfortunately, it doesn't stretch for bigger screen resolutions. Is there a way to make the theme adjust or switch background images for different screen sizes?

Comment: That is the problem with  background images (and responsive websites)… in that case unset the background image, and use conditional CSS with the class `.mk-header-bg.mk-background-stretch {background-image: url('/myImage.jpg') !important;}`. The conditional CSS are like `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {}`. So you will use different sizes of your image.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Very helpful.

Comment: Exactly what I need. The media query solution with a set of sized images wins the day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the current background from the overlaying elements. Then you can add you background to the header and it will be seen.

```
.mk-header-bg.mk-background-stretch,
.mk-header-toolbar {
    background: none;
}
.mk-header-holder {
    background-image: url('/myImage.jpg');
}
```